# Unable to run java application on tomcat in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, java-11, tomcat9

I am trying to create a simple docker image which runs a java application. I have the .jar file and here's my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM tomcat:9-jdk11
COPY <my-application>.jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

here's my `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  my-java-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

and here's the docker container logs:

```
my-app-docker-1-1  | NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.318 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.76
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.327 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 5 2023 07:17:04 UTC
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.76.0
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.19.0-45-generic
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /opt/java/openjdk
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.19+7
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.331 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Eclipse Adoptium
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.331 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.332 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.364 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.364 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.367 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.367 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.368 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.368 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.369 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.369 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.370 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.370 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.381 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.37] using APR version [1.7.0].
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.383 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.383 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:05.398 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022]
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:06.554 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:06.625 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1966] milliseconds
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:06.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:06.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.76]
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:06.835 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
my-app-docker-1-1  | 21-Jun-2023 12:32:06.874 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [247] milliseconds
```

It's basically stuck here. How do I fix this?
Here's what I get when I open `localhost:8080` on browser: https://imgur.com/a/Lg8iedB

Comment: It looks as if it's working. Is the service available on port 8080?

Comment: No, it's not. I am getting 404 not found

Comment: That's important information. It means we know that tomcat is starting up successfully and responding to requests. It's been a while since I worked with tomcat, but don't you usually deploy a `.war` file?

Comment: It's not a `.war` file. It's a `.jar` file. I am not a java developer so I don't really know the difference.
This is the error when I open `localhost:8080`: https://imgur.com/a/Lg8iedB

Comment: I don't know all possibilities, so maybe there is some way to deploy a jar, but as stated, typically you deploy a war file. If this is some third party thing you have, and it is distributed as a jar file, and it really is meant to be a web app, then it may be a self-hosting jar (a la Spring Boot). In that case it already has Tomcat embedded in it, so you just run the jar directly (kind of like any executable), instead of hosting it on a Tomcat server.

Comment: can you run command docker container ls -a and check what port number it showing

Comment: @Dex That makes sense. So I tried deploying it with openjdk image. The spring application ran but then I got `communication link failure` even though I have the database setup and running.

Comment: @Nidhi257 I only have portainer running. My webapp uses port 8080 since it uses tomcat
`CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND        CREATED       STATUS         PORTS                                                                                            NAMES
1cb50ba8ede8   portainer/portainer-ce:latest   "/portainer"   4 weeks ago   Up 7 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9443->9443/tcp, :::9443->9443/tcp, 9000/tcp   portainer`

Comment: can you also try hitting localhost:9443 or localhost:9000?

Comment: So it seems that was your first problem then, which you are now past (running it directly via the openjdk image). For the communication link failure, a lot more information will be needed. What image is it? What is your container setup and what order are they being launched in? What is the stack trace of the error? etc.

Comment: @Nidhi257 @Dex Thank you both of you for help! I really really appreciated it.
I was using `localhost` in jdbc url when in fact it should be the actual IP address. Can't connect to mysql instance because containers are isolated and `localhost` is specific for each container as well as the host where docker is installed. Oops.